# Jquery one click two function

Tags: jquery, function, this

I want to execute 2 functions on click.
Separately, both work great.
However, I have a problem when I execute functionA and after functionB.

The problem come frome the functionB. I think it's because of the $(this).
It don't get the correct id because of all the precedent var executed on the functionA.
THe id call by $(this) must be #prev-ajax,#next-ajax .

Here the code :

```
function A(){
    var link = $(this); 
    ajaxify(link.attr('href'));
    window.location.hash = link.attr("href");
    $('.link').removeClass('current');
}
function B(){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var link = $(".link[href*= '" + href + "']:not(#prev-ajax, #next-ajax)");
    var $parent = link.parents('.element');
    var prev = $parent.prev().find('.link').attr('href');
    var next = $parent.next().find('.link').attr('href');
    $("#prev-ajax").attr( 'href', prev );
    $("#next-ajax").attr( 'href', next ); 
}
$("#prev-ajax,#next-ajax").click(A).click(B);
```

Sorry for English, I'm french

Loïc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once and see if you are still having issue using both of the functions together:

```
$("#prev-ajax,#next-ajax").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var functionAlink = $(this);
    var functionBlink = $(this);

    // Function A code
    ajaxify(functionAlink.attr('href'));
    window.location.hash = functionAlink.attr("href");
    $('.link').removeClass('current');

    // Function B code
    var href = functionBlink.attr('href');
    var link = $(".link[href*= '" + href + "']:not(#prev-ajax, #next-ajax)");
    var $parent = link.parents('.element');
    var prev = $parent.prev().find('.link').attr('href');
    var next = $parent.next().find('.link').attr('href');
    $("#prev-ajax").attr('href', prev);
    $("#next-ajax").attr('href', next);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Both function works great and one after the other!!